# Is there a free/open source load balancing software I can use?

Tags: windows-server-2003, web-server, load-balancing, web-hosting

I need to do some load balancing testing on a website. Are there any free programs out there I can install and start using in a windows server 2003 environment? Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 3):

How about using the [Network Load Balancing Service (NLB)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758834%28WS.10%29.aspx) that comes with Windows Server 2003?

[Here's an article about setting up a web farm with NLB on Win2k3](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/loadbalancing/networkloadbalancingwindows2003.asp)